# Flask send data from form to relationship column

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am working in Flask and I am trying to take data from SelectMultipleField form and have it populate a one to many relationship field, in my "Template" model that is named "categories"

models.py: Each template should be able to have one or more Category(s).

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    template_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('template.id'))

class Template(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    categories = db.relationship('Category', backref='template_categories', lazy='dynamic')
```

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/temps/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def create_template():
    my_choices = get_choices()
    form = TemplateForm()
    form.categories.choices = my_choices
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        template = Template(name = form.name.data,
                            categories=form.categories.data)
        db.session.add(template)
        
        ###WHAT GOES HERE TO WRITE TO Template.categories?

        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('my_templates'))
    else:
        print(form.errors)
    return render_template('temps/create_template.html', title='Create Template', form=form)
```

My forms.py:

```
class TemplateForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Display Name', validators = [DataRequired()])
    categories = SelectMultipleField('Template Categories', choices=[])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit Template')
```

**Question**

1. How do I take the list of values from the form.categories.data and add it to the "template" object so that it can be written to the Template table?

Edit: Updated after fixing error

Comment: Can you conform that the one-to-many relationship is correct? I believe you mean to have a many-to-many relationship i.e. one template has many categories and one category can be in many templates.

Comment: @pjcunningham - It is as you describe it where a Template can have several categories, and a category can be in several templates.
So perhaps I need to use an "association" table?

Comment: Correct and the assignment `categories=form.categories.data`  in the `Template` instance creation is sufficient to set a template's categories.